# How can I get a 'square' <mx:Box> whitch width equals height in Flex4？

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

In Flex4, I want to make sure a `<mx:Box>` component is squre (width = height), the width is "100%" which inherit from the parent component. But`<mx:Box width="100%" height="width">` or `<mx:Box width="100%" height="{height}">` doesn't work. How can I make it? Thx a lot!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<mx:Box width="{parent.width}" height="{parent.width}">
```

Alternatively, use

```
<mx:Box width="100%" height="{myBox.width}" id="myBox">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's work. But if my parent component has padding, is there some value looks like that I can set height="{self.width}"?

Comment: Thanks~Pranav~It's exactly what I needed!